# Rectangle area and perimeter

Tags: geometry

If a rectangle area is $20$ cm<sup>$2$</sup>,
which one is larger:
rectangle perimeter or $21 cm$ ?

I know $A=l*w$
and $P=2(l+w)$
since we have $A=20$ cm<sup>$2$</sup>, then either $l$ or $w= \sqrt{20}$ cm<sup>$2$</sup>
if we can say that is the $l$, then $w$ must be less than $\sqrt{20}$ so the rectangle perimeter will be larger but how can we make sure that $\sqrt{20}$ is for $l$ not $w$.

Comment: The rectangle perimeter could be very large (think of a long, thin rectangle).  The lower bound would be a perfect square.  If it is a perfect square $l=w = \sqrt{20}$ and $P = 4\sqrt{20}$

Comment: so we cannot determine which one is larger, the perimeter or 21cm because there is more than one possibility.

Comment: Since $4\sqrt{20} < 21$, could be smaller or larger.